# scheduled email release

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron, scheduled-tasks, actionmailer

what will be the best method of releasing a scheduled email say 2 days before an event in RoR. the event date is going to be stored into the database, and i just want a reminder sent out 2 days prior to event.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

in your schedule.rb file

```
every 1.day do
   trigger mailer
end
```

and in mailer method

```
def mail_setup
  if Date.today == event_date - 2.days
     mail setup
  else
     do nothing
  end
end
```

Comment: havent had a chance to test as yet

Answer (score 0):

You might have figured this alreay out by yourself. Well...anyway: In cases as the described I always use an external crontab job. In a certain interval (in your case e.g. each day) you dial into your application via

```
rails runner script.rb
```

or

```
rails runner -e class-method
```

The script or the method then scans the db for pending trigger dates and does whatever it should do, e.g. sending emails.

ps: Of course you have to take care of the correct environment for your rails calls.

Comment: havent had a chance to test as yet